# HTTP Redirects caused by public hotspots

Tags: http, proxy, wifi, public

When a user connects for the first time to a public hotspot they often get back a welcome page with a login, instead of the requested page. This can also happen when you request a page from code, leading to corruption. We expect this type of page should always return a "302 redirect", but hard evidence that this always happens is hard to come by and we think some users may be getting back corrupted data - with a 200 return from hotspots in the world.

Does anyone know what the correct behaviour of a hotspot is, and the way to avoid it getting into the flow?

This also goes for proxies that downsample images over 3G connections etc. We have resorted to hashing our files with an integrity check to throw out altered data, but this seems a very heavy weight solution.

Note: we're happy with the data being proxied, we just want it left unaltered.

Answer (score 2):

The correct status code for this case would be status code 511 (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6585.html#status-511)

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. We're filtering out anything but 200s so hopefully outright wrong data should be covered. However I think gateway proxies downsampling images to reduce bandwidth is still a problem. Any clues on how to tell them to go away? I just want an unimpeded http connection!