# Domain forwarding : redirect to a site in a private network

Tags: http, servlets, networking

I have a private network at home. 
moreover, I have a private siten And what i want, if someone connects to my network for the first time And for his first http request for example, if he enters www.google.com should be redirected to www.mysite.com
would you have a track how to do that?

for example, you connect to my network, you open a web browser, you type www.site.com for the first time I want you to be redirected to my www.myprivatesite.com I will not redirect users from google but an interceptor who intercepts this request and redirects to another site

Answer (score 1):

You could [set a cookie](https://www.php.net/setcookie) for every user and generally check if that cookie exists, so you would know if he already visited your site or not like:

```
if ($_COOKIE['checkUser']) { ... }
```

But you can't redirect users from google.com to your site. If you mean that you want to track where the user comes from, you should have a look at [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/#/provision).

Comment: for example, you connect to my network, you open a web browser, you type www.site.com
for the first time I want you to be redirected to my www.myprivatesite.com
I will not redirect users from google but an interceptor who intercepts this request and redirects to another site

Comment: Do I understand correctly: For example you have `Charafi.org` and you want to redirect ALL users to `Charafi.com`?

Comment: no, suppose you have just been connected to my wifi at home.
You open a browser you type www.google.com
for the first time i want you to be redirected to charafi.com

Comment: Ah ok. Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892333/http-redirects-caused-by-public-hotspots